# kafkajs disconnect занимает много времени

Tags: javascript, typescript, apache-kafka

Использую либу [kafkajs](https://kafka.js.org/docs/consumer-example) для автотестов.

При вызове `await consumer.disconnect()` - команда выполняется около 5ти секунд, есть какие-то варианты безопасного и быстрого дисконнекта?

Comment: дополнительно еще тут спросил
https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/issues/1606

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло это решение:

```
The maximum amount of time in milliseconds the server will block before 
answering the fetch request if there isn’t sufficient data to immediately 
satisfy the requirement given by minBytes
```

Тем самым надо выставить `minBytes: 0`, либо `maxWaitTimeInMs: 0`

по умолчанию в кафке `maxWaitTimeInMs: 5000`(ms), `minBytes: 1`

```
const consumer = this.client.consumer({
    minBytes: 0, // достаточно любой из этих опций
    maxWaitTimeInMs: 0,
    ...
});
```